# Modeling: Parallel Queue with dependencies

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, queue

i have a quite complicated set up and need some input how to resolve it.

I have a process A that consists of Task 1,2a,2b,2c,3a,3b,3c and 4.

Task 1 has to run first with no one else of those tasks in parallel.

Task 2a,2b,2c have to run one after another but can be executed in parallel with 3a,3b,3c (which also have to be run one after another. Task 4 can only be run after 3c and 2c are done.

I first implemented this via Priority Queue and tried to manage it with Priorities and a mechanism that only dequeues only one of a kind meaning 2a and 3a could be dequeued the same time, 2b and 3b and so on.

But then if 3a is done and could start 3b, it has to wait until 2a is also done. I need an idea of a queue mechanism that can handle my situation some how. I know it is complicated but any hint would probably help me.

Comment: TPL Dataflow for the win. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tpl+dataflow

Comment: this is quite a broad question, can you narrow down the problem and maybe post some existing code? Its hard to answer this briefly.

Comment: You need to block after each parallel group of tasks are run.  You can use a WaitHandler to block.  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Whith `async` and `await` your solution would look like this (assuming you have methods `Run...Async` to run your individual tasks and that return the tasks):

```
async Task RunTasks2Async() {
     await RunTask2aAsync();
     await RunTask2bAsync();
     await RunTask2cAsync();
}

async Task RunTasks3Async() {
     await RunTask3aAsync();
     await RunTask3bAsync();
     await RunTask3cAsync();
}

async Task RunAllTasks()
{
    await RunTask1();
    Task task2 = RunTasks2Async();
    Task task3 = RunTasks3Async();
    await Task.WhenAll(task2, task3);
    await RunTask4Async();
}
```

If you want to not use `async`/ `await`, you can use `Task.ContinueWith` for the serial execution of your tasks and `Task.WhenAll` for  the parallel execution.